# Extract package names from R scripts

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to write a function to extract package names from a list of R script files. My regular expression do not seem to be working and I am not sure why. For begginers, I am not able to match lines that include `library`. For example

```
str <- c("           library(abc)", "library(def)", "some other text")
grep("library\\(", str, value = TRUE)
grep("library\\(+[A-z]\\)", str, value = TRUE)
```

Why does my second `grep` do not return elements 1 and 2 from the `str` vector? I have tried so many options but all my results come back empty.

Answer (score 3):

Your second `grep` does not return  1,2 for two reasons.

1. You used value=TRUE which makes it return the matching string instead of the
   location. and
2. You misplaced the +.  You want`grep("library\\(\\w+\\)", str)`

Comment: Looks like I was beaten to the answer.  But you might want to swap `[A-z]` for `[[:alnum:]]` - some libraries, like ggplot2, involve numerals.  Note that some folks use `require(<package_name>)` instead of `library(<package_name>)`

Comment: Yes,  I will edit the answer with a slightly different solution.

Comment: Just a simple correction; I do not want the indices but I want the actual strings so `value = TRUE` is what I need. Such an ID 10T mistake! Thanks also for the suggestion about including numbers. I have it in my version but wanted to provide the simplest example I could think of. I definitely need to go back to read some regex info.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like something a bit more robust that will handle some edge cases (`library()` takes a number of parameters and the `package` one can be a name/symbol or a string and doesn't necessarily have to be specified first):

```
library(purrr)

script <-  '
library(js) ; library(foo)
#
library("V8")
ls()
library(package=rvest)
TRUE
library(package="hrbrthemes")
1 + 1
library(quietly=TRUE, "ggplot2")
library(quietly=TRUE, package=dplyr, verbose=TRUE)
'
x <- parse(textConnection(script)) # parse w/o eval

keep(x, is.language) %>%                       # `library()` is a language object
  keep(~languageEl(.x, 1) == "library") %>%    # other things are too, so only keep `library()` ones
  map(as.call) %>%                             # turn it into a `call` object 
  map(match.call, definition = library) %>%    # so we can match up parameters and get them in the right order
  map(languageEl, 2) %>%                       # language element 1 is `library`
  map_chr(as.character) %>%                    # turn names/symbols into characters
  sort()                                       # why not
## [1] "dplyr"      "foo"        "ggplot2"    "hrbrthemes" "js"         "rvest"      "V8"
```

This won't catch `library()` calls within functions (it could be expanded to do that) but if top-level edge cases are infrequent, there is an even smaller likelihood of ones in functions (those wld likely use `require()` as well).